# Can anyone prove why this hyperbolic tiling works?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tiling, tessellations

Let's start with the following hyperbolic tiling.

[image: A (3,3,3,3,4,4) tiling]

It has four equilateral triangles and two squares meeting at every vertex. Its edge is about 1.06 absolute units (it's actually identical to the edge of {5,4}, but that's a whole other can of worms).

The issue is this: a numeric search shows that if you put one of these triangles and four of these squares together, there will be a tiny gap (around 2 degrees).
This gap just happens to perfectly correspond to an angle of an equilateral triangle whose edge is exactly 7 times the edge of this tiling.

Like so:

[image: Triangle-centered view]

Here's a view centered closer to the triangle's vertex so you could see how it fits:

[image: Close to the vertex]

This is one of those "I've seen it but I don't believe it" moments for me. How could I prove that this relation is valid (I only have numeric computations, but they hold for more than 100 decimals)?

Comment: I can't see how to answer this question at all without a lot more information. You write about *triangles* and *squares* with barely any quantitive information about the geometry of said triangles and squares, such as side measurements or angle measurements.

Comment: Take this statement for example: *if you put one triangle and four squares together, there will be a tiny gap (around 2 degrees)*. Well, that statement depends entirely on information that you have not given, regarding the angles of that triangle and those four squares.

Comment: But that information is not really necessary. The whole thing is based on a tiling with four equilateral triangles and two squares at a vertex -- that by itself uniquely specifies the edge length, as well as the angles of all polygons involved. I have also mentioned that the edge length is identical to edge of {5,4}.

Comment: You should add the information about *equilateral* triangles to your post, that was missing.

Comment: Alright, I added that. I've been so involved with regular polygons lately I'm forgetting to specify that.

Comment: What comes to mind is hyperbolic trig. If $\alpha$, $\beta$ denote the angles of the yellow triangle and red squares, then $2\pi = 4 \alpha + 3 \beta$. Also the angle of the purple triangle is $\gamma = 2 \pi - (\alpha + 4 \beta) = 3\alpha - \beta$. Letting $L$ be the common side length of the triangles and squares, you can then plug into hyperbolic trig formulas for regular triangles and regular squares to determine $L$ analytically, and then perhaps you can check whether $\gamma$ and $7L$ satisfy the hyperbolic trig formula for regular triangles, by fooling around with identities.

Comment: Would be 2π=4α+2β, not 3β.